# Cross Type LINQ

Tags: .net, linq

I have the following code

```
    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethod]
    public void TestEnumOfMaybe()
    {
        List<Maybe<int>> l = new List<Maybe<int>>();
        l.Add(1.ToMaybe());
        l.Add(Maybe.None<int>());
        l.Add(3.ToMaybe());

        var y = from x in l
                from y in x
                select y;

    }
```

My Maybe type accepts all the Select and SelectMany methods to make it Linq compatible and I have tests to prove it so. However I can't seem to figure out a way to do cross type LINQ composition as in the above test case. The error I get is

```
expression of type 'FunctionalExtensions.Maybe<int>' is not allowed in
a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type
'System.Collections.Generic.List<FunctionalExtensions.Maybe<int>>'.  

Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.
FunctionalExtensions*
```

Is there a way to combine the two LINQ types or am I out of luck here? The complete Maybe.cs implementation is at

https://gist.github.com/4016243

Comment: Please show your ToMaybe function. and MayBe's definition.

Comment: Is that necessary? I'm asking a general question about combining Monads/Linq types in c#?. Is it possible in the general case or not. My implementation of Maybe is not so important I think.

Comment: Of course I could just make my Maye implement IEnumerable but that is not quite what I'm looking for in understanding. In fact my real problem involves IObservable<T> not IEnumerable<T>

Comment: FYI The full maybe implementation is at https://gist.github.com/4016243

Comment: How do you expect this work, without implementing IEnumerable? Actually your own SelectMany extension function is not related to IEnumerable SelectMany function (which you used it here).

Comment: It sounds like the `SelectMany` you have written does not meet the required signature. You really need to show the `SelectMany` signature/implementation.

Comment: The linked gist shows the implementation. See the end of the question.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing k; for the method to be LINQ-compatible **against a single instance**, the method would have to look like: `public static Maybe<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TMaybe, TResult>(this Maybe<TSource> m, Func<Maybe<TSource>, Maybe<TMaybe>> f, Func<Maybe<TSource>, Maybe<TMaybe>, TResult> g)` - your signature is wrong, frankly. And even then, it can't be used where `l` is a *list* - for that to work, `l` must be a maybe.

Comment: I don't understand. I have tests showing that LINQ for Maybe by itself is fine. It is combined with Enumerable where I can't figure out the sigs.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing your `SelectMany` for `Maybe<T>` doesn't even match the expected signature, so it can't be "fine" - can you show those tests maybe? however, you can't simply use the two in combination; `Enumerable.*` is **one** implementation - your custom one is a *completely separate* one. How do you expect to combine them here?

Comment: Hi Marc. My maybe tests are here. https://gist.github.com/4016445

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my specific problem it turns out that having Maybe implement IEnumerable is the way to go and it make supporting IOBservable trivial as well. My two test cases which now pass.

```
    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethod]
    public void TestEnumOfMaybe()
    {
        List<Maybe<int>> l = new List<Maybe<int>>();
        l.Add(1.ToMaybe());
        l.Add(Maybe.None<int>());
        l.Add(3.ToMaybe());

        var k = from q in l
                from y in q
                select y;

        k.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[] { 1, 3 });

    }

    [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethod]
    public void TestObservableOfMaybe()
    {
        List<Maybe<int>> l = new List<Maybe<int>>();
        l.Add(1.ToMaybe());
        l.Add(Maybe.None<int>());
        l.Add(3.ToMaybe());

        var o = l.ToObservable();

        var k = from q in o
                from y in q
                select y;

        var m = k.ToEnumerable();

        m.Should().BeEquivalentTo(new[] { 1, 3 });

    }
```

In general I think the LINQ system forbids chaining different types together even if the SelectMany signatures will line up. I'm yet to be convinced otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

The translation of this:

```
// Changed variable from y to query for clarity
var query = from x in l
            from y in x
            select y;
```

is simply:

```
var query = l.SelectMany(x => x, (x, y) => y);
```

Note that *nothing* is being called on `y` here.

Now `l` is a `List<Maybe<int>>`, so you need to try to find an appropriate `SelectMany` method which would be valid here. Unless you've added any more, it will look in [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345618.aspx), and *every* overload there requires the the first delegate to return an `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T`.

So that's why it's not working. You could make it work by making `Maybe<T>` implement `IEnumerable<T>` (presumably either yielding a single result or no results). It's hard to say for sure whether that's what you're aiming for, but you've basically got to get that expansion to work.

Alternatively, you could write a new overload for `SelectMany` targeting `IEnumerable<T>`, for cases where the result is a `Maybe<T>` rather than an `IEnumerable<T>`. That would be pretty unintuitive though, IMO.

Comment: Intuitively I want to flatten an IEnumerable<Maybe<T>> to IEnumerable<T> filtering out the None<T>. Shouldn't there be an intuitive neat solution to this?

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: I'd probably just use a `Where` call to filter, then a `Select` call to unwrap...

Comment: Or another way to do that would be for `Maybe<T>` to implement `IEnumerable<T>`, and just have `None<T>` do a `yield break;`, and the others do a `yield return Value();` - then you can just use regular LINQ without any of these custom extension methods whatsoever /cc @bradgonesurfing (edit: which I think Jon alluded to in his answer). Personally, I'd just want to do a `Where` on a new `HasValue` boolean property though ;p

Answer (score 1):

Your `SelectMany` method takes a `Maybe<TSource>` as a parameter, but you're using it on a `List<Maybe<TSource>>`, so it actually uses the `SelectMany` method from `Enumerable`. It's not clear from your example what you expect the type of `y` to be, but as it is the code doesn't really make sense.

Comment: In this case I guess the type of y should be IEnumerable. I agree it is underspecified in the code. That's part of the confusion I guess. Do you have a suggestion on a SelectMany implementation that would work and how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

As Jon notes, the LINQ translation of `from`,`from` to `SelectMany` is:

```
var query = l.SelectMany(x => x, (x, y) => y);
```

The first thing to note is that your `SelectMany` is defined against an individual `Maybe<T>`, so for this to make sense, `l` must be a `Maybe<T>` (for some `T`), not a list. The next thing to note is that the signature has to match. For example:

```
public static Maybe<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TMaybe, TResult>(
    this Maybe<TSource> m, Func<Maybe<TSource>, Maybe<TMaybe>> f,
    Func<Maybe<TSource>, Maybe<TMaybe>, TResult> g)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
    // return m.Bind(x => f(x).Bind(y => g(x, y).ToMaybe()));
}
```

And:

```
var obj = l[0];
```

Now this works (explicit generics):

```
var q = obj.SelectMany<int, int, Maybe<int>>((x => x), (x, y) => y);
```

which is identical to:

```
var r = obj.SelectMany((x => x), (x, y) => y);
```

which is identical to:

```
var query = from x in obj
            from y in x
            select y;
```

Comment: But making obj a single instance defeats the intent of the question which was to flatten a list<Maybe<T>> to list<T>. If your answer focused on this point that I just don't understand it sorry.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing which sounds more like classic LINQ... you could write an extension method of `SelectMany` from an `IEnumerable<Maybe<T>>` that goes to `IEnumerable<T>`, but frankly I'm not quite sure why you can't just do something like `var y = from x in l select x.Value()`.

Comment: Actually var y = from x in l select x.Value() where x.IsSome(); For sure I can do this and I probably will as it looks to be quite hard to come up with another solution.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing the `where` needs to come before the `select`, but basically: yes